Finding the number of previous tickets in the last 30 days
I'm trying to add a column for "number of tickets in the last 30 days" to a query of all tickets in 2024. What I've got so far:
SELECT customer_id,
       ticket_number,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY customer_id
           ORDER BY receive_dt DESC
       ) AS "Num Tickets Last 30 Days"
FROM tickets
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM receive_dt) = 2024

The above works great, except that it's giving me a count of all tickets for the year (b/c that's  what my WHERE is looking at, of course).
Is there any way to restrict an Ordered Analytical Function by date instead of the number of rows?  What should I be using instead?

You don’t need a window function, just a sub-query

SELECT t0.customer_id,
   t0.ticket_number,
   (SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM tickets t1
    WHERE t0.customer_id = t1.customer_id
    AND t1.receive_dt >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY
   ) AS "Num Tickets Last 30 Days"
FROM tickets t0
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t0.receive_dt) = 2024


For this need I would normally suggest use of a "lateral join" subquery instead of using an analytical function. However, Teradata doesn't (at the time of answering) support this join type, so a more conventional SQL approach is to use a "correlated subquery" within the select clause.
SELECT
      t.customer_id
    , t.ticket_number
    , ( SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tickets sub
        WHERE sub.customer_id = t.customer_id
            AND sub.receive_dt >= t.receive_dt - INTERVAL '30' DAY
            AND sub.receive_dt < t.receive_dt
        ) AS Num_Tickets_Last_30_Days
FROM tickets t
WHERE t.receive_dt >= DATE '2024-01-01'
AND t.receive_dt < DATE '2025-01-01'
ORDER BY
      t.customer_id
    , t.ticket_number

Correlated subqueries like this can be problematical for performance.
Note I recommend the use of a date range instead for your where clause instead of using the function extract on each row. (Typically functions used in a where clause that way rob the optimizer of access to indexes potentially making the query slower than it needs to be.)
Note also that the subquery will include a count of rows up to 30 days before '2024-01-01'. e.g. if a ticket exists on '2024-01-01' then a ticket bought 2 days before will be counted. This is different to your original query which would have excluded all rows prior to '2024-01-01'.

In my initial response to this question I though (incorrectly) that Teradata supported lateral joins through an "apply operator" similar to SQL Server. For that product the alternative to the "correletd subquery" seen above would be:
SELECT
      t.customer_id
    , t.ticket_number
    , oa.Num_Tickets_Last_30_Days
FROM tickets t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Num_Tickets_Last_30_Days
    FROM tickets sub
    WHERE sub.customer_id = t.customer_id
        AND sub.receive_dt >= t.receive_dt - INTERVAL '30' DAY
        AND sub.receive_dt < t.receive_dt
    ) AS oa
WHERE t.receive_dt >= DATE '2024-01-01' 
AND t.receive_dt < DATE '2025-01-01'
ORDER BY
      t.customer_id
    , t.ticket_number

Or, for other products such as Postgres the lateral join syntax would be like this:
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Num_Tickets_Last_30_Days
    FROM tickets sub
    WHERE sub.customer_id = t.customer_id
        AND sub.receive_dt >= t.receive_dt - INTERVAL '30' DAY
        AND sub.receive_dt < t.receive_dt
    ) AS oa ON true

The big advantage of lateral joins (or the apply operator equivalent) is these perform better than traditional "correlated subqueries".

Teradata does not support CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY, that's SQL Server syntax.

Thanks, I stand corrected, and, apparently Teradata doesn't (yet) support lateral joins at all. So, the only alternative I can suggest will be an correlated subquery.
